# Finding large integer squares - how to decide modulus to calculate.

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Say I want to decide if an integer is a square. My integer is rather big so I can't keep it in memory altogether, but I know that it is a product

$$f = \prod_{i=1}^nf_i,  f_i\in \mathbb{N}$$
Then I remember something like this which may be useful
$$(ak+b)^2 \equiv b^2\mod a$$ I also know that for a product each factor modulo can be multiplied together and then modulied again. This can be seen as in th expression : $\prod(ka_i+b_i)$, only term not any k:s in it will be the last term: $\prod b_i$

I know that if I do modulo on the product and it is not $b^2$ mod $a$, then I can say that it is not a square. But can I be sure to select such an $a$ or do I have to try all the $a$s in the world?

Comment: Relevant: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudosquare.html

Comment: It seems to me that 0,1,4 are the only values mod 8 can take for squares. So I can accidentally even get really special primes which have same modularity. But is there some systematic approach to combine different moduli to be sure of squareness?